# How to override global variable definitions using TS

Tags: typescript, browser, tsc

For our app at work, I want to encourage people to use a wrapper around `localStorage` that automatically converts to/from JSON (and also has type-checking in place). I tried to override the global TS definition for window.localStorage:

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    localStorage: null,
  }
}
```

but that didn't really do anything - is there a way to prevent the use of window.localStorage from compiling and even better giving the user a useful warning about why it doesn't compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

say if you just put the

```
 interface Window {
    localStorage: null,
  }
```

in the declaration file that is [global](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/global-d-ts.html), and put that file in some place in your project that the TSC compiler (VS Code linter) knows about, then you would not even need that `import './our-defs.d.ts'`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, nevermind, this did work, but I had to explicitly import the file:

```
import './our-defs.d.ts'
```

however if anyone knows how to provide a custom error message somehow, that would be awesome.